# Capturing output from bash script run using os.system() python

Tags: python

I'm using Python to run a bash script using `os.system`. The problem is that the bash executable prints so many outputs to the console which is spamming my screen. Is there any way to block all the print calls from such external routines/modules in python?

Here is a small toy example showing the problem,

I have a small bash script which makes a file and prints this text

```
#!/bin/bash
touch "SomeFile.dat"
echo "Spam Spam Spam Spam"
echo "Spam Spam Spam Spam"
echo "Spam Spam Spam Spam"
echo "Spam Spam Spam Spam"
```

and I have this python file which calls this bash file

```
import os
print ("Job starting") #text1
os.system("./blue.sh")
print  ("Job finished") #text2
```

So when I run this, I want text1 and text2 to be printed and to block all outputs from the bash script. How can we do this in Python?

**P.S: I can not edit the bash-script, I want to achieve this through Python.**

Comment: `os.system("./blue.sh > /dev/null")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [os.system()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) **does not** provide a way to capture the stdout of the process which is run.

> **os.system(command)**
>
> Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by
> calling the Standard C function system(), and has the same
> limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in the
> environment of the executed command. If command generates any output,
> it will be sent to the interpreter standard output stream. The C
> standard does not specify the meaning of the return value of the C
> function, so the return value of the Python function is
> system-dependent.

The [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function.

Using `subprocess.run()` you can define `stdin` and `stdout` of the spawned process. If you want to ignore the stdout and stderr of the process, you can redirect it to [subprocess.DEVNULL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL)

```
import subprocess
print("Job starting") #text1
subprocess.run(["./blue.sh"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
print("Job finished") #text2
```

should produce the desired result of only logging the print statements but not the output of the `blue.sh`

If you want to suppress only the `stdout` and not the `stderr` then you can remove the `stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` from the `subprocess.run()` arguments.